# Decrement and assignment operator in java

Tags: java

Can somebody explain why output of the code below is 1.

```java
int i = 1;
i=i--;
System.out.println(i); // 1
```

Comment: You should do `i = --i`

Comment: @Mr.White, even better `i--;` or `--i;`

Comment: Your use-case is the actually the expected behaviour.

Comment: it's better to write i-- or i -= 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`i--` does the following steps:

- return the value of `i`
- decrement `i` by 1

so the statement `i = i--` does the following:

- `i` is returned (the statement now equals `i = 1`)
- `i` is decremented (i is now 0)
- the statement (the assignment) is now done (`i = 1`)

In the end `i` is 1

---

To make it a bit more clear you could say the line `i = i--;` does pretty much the same as this code:

```
int j = i;
i = i-1;
i = j;
```